# Ajax с cookie или Ajax с авторизацией на сервере

Tags: ajax, javascript, cookie, get

Есть на сайте php скрипт, который отдаёт JSON по GET запросу. Нужно Ajax-ом получить эти данные в JavaScript, другого сайта. Проблема в том что если не пройдена авторизация (т.е. cookie нет), то скрипт возвращает null.

Вопрос: как послать Ajax с cookie ?

Comment: Если куки нет, то его надо создать :)

Comment: мне кажется проблема не в куках, а в кросдоменном аякс-запросе

Comment: Кросдоменностью все в порядке - я вижу ответ php-скрипта:  

    callback_r12({"statur":"ok","result":null})

А должен видеть вместо null некие данные.

Comment: А может надо посмотреть как реализована авторизация, небось через сессию? Вот прпробуйте её и передать.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ЕМНИП аякс не будет посылать куки на другой домен просто так... ну как бы это логично)
смотрите в сторону настроек аякса, в частности **crossDomain** и **xhr** [jquery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Comment: Спасибо буду пробовать.